# how to take screenshot by system screenshot app in java android

Tags: java, android, screenshot

i want to take screenshot by android default screenshot app not with bitmap or other ways.

[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)

i tried this one but i want just send a request for screenshot to phone screenshot app not taking that with my app code.

is there any solution?

Comment: I do not believe that this is an option, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe there isn't any way,thanks